# Using "Ctrl" as a shortcut in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm still learning about chords in VScode, but there's one thing that still doesn't make sense to me.

I use the visual GUI for editing my keyboard shortcuts, and I'd like to make it so that just pressing `Ctrl` by itself closes a menu. I've found the command that I want to trigger, but after activating the debugger, all I see is

```
[2021-05-22 07:42:11.603] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
[2021-05-22 07:42:11.604] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
[2021-05-22 07:42:11.604] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
[2021-05-22 07:42:11.764] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: + Storing single modifier for possible chord ctrl.
[2021-05-22 07:42:12.065] [renderer1] [info] [KeybindingService]: + Clearing single modifier due to 300ms elapsed.
```

However, I don't think I have any commands that actually "chord" `Ctrl`.

For example, if I try to do `Ctrl+A` by typing `Ctrl` followed by `A`, it fails. I have to do `Ctrl` and `A` both at the same time. And I believe that this is true of all of my `Ctrl` commands: there are no chords. As soon as I lift up `Ctrl`, it's clear that all I wanted to press was `Ctrl` and that's it.

So here are my questions:

1. How do I get `Ctrl` to be a keyboard shortcut by itself?
2. How do I see which commands with `Ctrl` in them are in fact chorded (ideally from the GUI)? (in case I'm wrong and I am missing some chorded keyboard shortcut that starts with `Ctrl`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vscode defines "chords" as

> Chords (two separate keypress actions) are described by separating the
> two keypresses with a space. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

- from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-rules

Emacs describes a "key-chord" like so:

> Key-chord lets you bind commands to combinations of key-strokes. Here
> a “key chord” means two keys pressed simultaneously, or a single key
> quickly pressed twice. (*)

- from https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyChord

Either way vscode has a lot of keychords that use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+.

The only way to use a modifier key, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, alone as a keybinding is as follows:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl ctrl",                // note no + between the keys
  "command": "<your command here>"
}
```

You do have to hit them fairly quickly in sequence.